# Add Url to Button ( Open in WebView - not default Safari ) - Multiple Scenes app - Objective C

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I am stuck at a problem for more thant 2 moths, and because i am not a native english and just a beginner Xcode learner, i must ask for your help.

I am building an app: First view is the cover and a button to Enter into the menu of the app

I make transition through a navigation controller, to a second view (table view with multiple table view scenes). Every table view scene style is subtitle.

When you push on a subtitle, it takes you to another view where i have written some things, added a gradient photo as background and PLACED a BUTTON to the bottom at the page.

This is my problem: I what that in the moment i push the button , a web view to open (another scene - is ok if it's open in safari, but i want a web view in my app ) - opening the url i give him (google) for example.

i found a great tutorial:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=rTr3WfCd0Y0&list=PLdjWe9acbChNKm83UFeQE6E9Tdch5Kayc&index=28

**But this method is not good if you have multiple scenes...i cannot link the button from the scene i want in View controller.h pushing ctrl+click...it does not work! Only in single view app.** what i do not understand?

[image: screenshot]

I feel exhausted for two months - i cannot find answer. Please explain me hot to do...like you are talking to a stupid person...

I have very few knowledge objective c... must i import the Scene i want to link button to url in View Controller.h? How to do that? Why that method doesn't work in multiple scenes? What i do wrong? What i do not make? ....

Comment: Your use of the word 'scene' is confusing here.  Are you talking about table view cells? (UITableViewCell).  And is the issue that you want to change the URL you open, depending on which cell has been clicked on?  To get help with this I'd need to understand the issue exactly!  Thanks.

Comment: In short are you want to  open `url` into safari rather then you application?

Comment: Hi Alexandru, you don't have to create separate view controllers for each subtitle you want to tap. If I have understood correctly, I assume what you want is to show a list with many subtitles. When you tap on a list, a view comes up with a picture and a button at the bottom. tapping on the button redirecets to a webview or to the native browser.

Answer (score 0):

1)Add one more viewcontroller (name it as WebViewController)to your project and give storyboard id as SBWebView

2)Place a WebView in viewcontroller (WebViewController) and link it to(WebViewController.h) as

```
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIWebView *webView;
```

3)Declare a string Variable in WebViewController.h as

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) NSString *urlToOpen;
```

4)Add this code in viewDidLoad (WebViewController.m)

```
    NSURL *targetURL = [NSURL URLWithString:self.urlToOpen];

    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:targetURL];

    [self.webView loadRequest:request];
```

5)Add this code to UrlButton action

```
WebViewController *webVC = [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"SBWebView"];

[webVC urlToOpen:@"www.google.com"];//URL To Open

[self.navigationController pushViewController:webVC animated:YES];
```